# Perl iterate through list of URLS and extra files

Tags: perl, url, while-loop, lwp

I have a list of json files I need to download. I placed the URLs in a txt file called URL_FILE_LIST.txt the values of that file are:

```
https://www.fema.gov/api/open/v1/DeclarationDenials.json
https://www.fema.gov/api/open/v2/DisasterDeclarationsSummaries.json
```

The perl script I am calling looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use LWP::Simple;


my $file = 'URL_FILE_LIST.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
        getstore($line , basename($line));
        last if $. == 2;
}

close $info;
```

When I print the parts of the getstore, it looks right, I am able to see the URL and the base name.  The issue is that nothing happens.

When i get rid of the loop and just pass it the URL as an ARG[0] it works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

I have removed the While loop and passed in the URL as  ARG[0] and it works fine.

Comment: I'd guess that the issue is the missing `chomp $line` in the loop.

Comment: You are correct!!!

Answer (score 2):

Adding `chomp` solved the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use LWP::Simple;


my $file = 'URL_FILE_LIST.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {  
       chomp $line;
        getstore( $line , basename( $line));
       last if $. == 2;
       }

close $info;
```